# Cannot access html element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to access the title of an html div element which is on the page, from a browser extension. When I console log the element in firefox and view it in the dev tools, I get this output:

```html
<div class="X" A="Y" B="Z" C="XX">
```

When I click the on the above to expand it, I get the list of element characteristics:

```
...
tagName: "DIV"
textContent: "what is in the text"
title: "what I want to get"
```

Yet, when I console log element.title I get an empty string. I get undefined when I do element.innerHTML, when there is clearly something there.

Comment: The element you've mentioned does not have title attribute

Comment: When I click on it, I get the expanded list of attributes which includes the title.

Answer (score 1):

If the element does not have a title attribute it won't log anything. I assume you might be seeing a different div, consider the following:

```js
console.log("class X div title: ", document.getElementsByClassName('X')[0].title);
console.log("class F div title: ", document.getElementsByClassName('F')[0].title);
//jQuery
console.log("class X div title: ", $(".X").prop('title'));
console.log("class F div title: ", $(".F").prop('title'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="X" A="Y" B="Z" C="XX">innerHTML for X</div>
<div class="F" A="Y" B="Z" C="XX" title="target title">innerHTML for F</div>
```

Comment: I am certain I am seeing the correct div. What I am doing is: 

 `console.log(element);`
 `console.log(element.title);`

Comment: @JohnAbelDoe could you try out the same in another browser, say chrome? Does it have the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access to the title of an htmlElement, it must be set on, on your example it haven't, take a look on mine :

```
<div class="X" A="Y" B="Z" C="XX" style="styleX" title="myAwesomeTitle">
```